# Carousel slider not working with Flexbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I'm trying to make a slider/carousel using simple HTML, CSS, and Javascript. I'm using Flexbox, which is the trouble. When clicking the arrows for moving the slide, there is no animation and the new image just pops up without sliding off to the left.

In regards to CSS, everything is Flexboxed, so any guides I have seen have not been too helpful. When trying out Flexbox/Carousel tutorial's they have far complicated my code.

Here is my code.

```js
(function() {

  var sliderWidth = $('.carousel-cells').width();

  var Carousel = {
    props: {
      current_slide: null,
      total_slides: null
    },
    init: function() {

      Carousel.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
      $(".carousel-next").on("click", function() {
        Carousel.next();
      });
      $(".carousel-prev").on("click", function() {
        Carousel.previous();
      });
      $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 37) {
          Carousel.previous();
        }
      });
      $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 39) {
          Carousel.next();
        }
      });
    },
    next: function() {

      $('.carousel-cells').animate({
          left: -sliderWidth
        }, 500,
        function() {
          $('article:first-child').appendTo('.carousel-cells');
          $('article').css('left', '');
        });
    },
    previous: function() {

      $('.carousel-cells').animate({
        left: +sliderWidth
      }, 500, function() {
        $('article:last-child').prependTo('.carousel-cells');
        $('article').css('left', '');
      });
    },
    update: function() {
      //will add code
    }
  }
  $(function() {
    Carousel.init();
  })
})(window);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  height: 100vh;
}

.page-content {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.page-content .main-carousel {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.page-content .main-carousel .carousel-next,
.page-content .main-carousel .carousel-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -25px;
}

.page-content .main-carousel .carousel-next {
  right: 0;
}

.page-content .main-carousel .carousel-prev {
  left: 0;
}

.page-content .main-carousel .carousel-cells {
  width: 99999px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.page-content .main-carousel .carousel-cells article {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  /*float:left;*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url('../img/slide-background.jpg');
}

.column-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 4vh 0 4vh 0;
}

.column-content h1 {
  margin: 0 0vh 2vh 6vh;
  font-size: 4vh;
}

.three-columns {
  display: flex;
  /*   -webkit-columns: 4 300px;
          -moz-columns: 4 250px;
         columns: 4 250px;*/
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 6vh 0vh 6vh;
}

.list-block h3 {
  margin-bottom: 2vh;
  padding-top: 1vh;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.slide-text h1 {
  font-size: 8vh;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .three-columns {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-content">
  <section class="main-carousel">
    <div class="carousel-next">&gt;</div>
    <div class="carousel-prev">&lt;</div>
    <div class="carousel-cells">
      <article>
        <div class="slide-text">
          <h1>Slide One</h1>
          <p>A slide about sliding slides.</p>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article>
        <div class="slide-text">
          <h1>Slide Two</h1>
          <p>A slide-sliding slider sliding slides.</p>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article>
        <div class="slide-text">
          <h1>Slide Three</h1>
          <p>A slide-sliding slider sliding slides.</p>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="column-content">
    <h1>Three Columns</h1>
    <div class="three-columns">
      <aside class="list-block">
        <h3>List Heading</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>List Item</li>
          <li>List Item</li>
          <li>List Item</li>
          <li>List Item</li>
          <li>List Item</li>
        </ul>
      </aside>
      <aside class="list-block">
        <h3>List Heading</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>List Item</li>
          <li>List Item</li>
          <li>List Item</li>
          <li>List Item</li>
          <li>List Item</li>
        </ul>
      </aside>
      <aside class="list-block">
        <h3>List Heading</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>List Item</li>
          <li>List Item</li>
        </ul>
      </aside>
      <aside class="list-block">
        <h3>List Heading</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>List Item</li>
          <li>List Item</li>
          <li>List Item</li>
        </ul>
      </aside>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

I looked at this for guidance: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mwYoOm?editors=0110 which was very helpful, but since I am using Flexbox, it failed to work.

Do you have any advice on what move to make or what could simply the Javascript to have it work correctly? Much appreciated!

Comment: Hi Amanda, you need to post the rest of your code so we have a working demo that reproduces the problem. We can't really help just seeing the javascript out of context since the problem is obviously also related to your HTML/CSS. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Updated my code. I'm trying to do it as simply as possible using just Vanilla Javascript and jQuery, as I see many plugins that would solve it more easily

Answer (score 0):

I commented my changes in the code below. What's still to be improved:

- **your selectors**. You cannot target `"article"` like that, it could target some "article" element from your page that has nothing to do with your gallery. Instead you should try to 1. store your gallery as a property and than target it's `"article"` children like: `Carousel.$slider.find("article")`
- By using generally `".carousel-cells"` you're limiting your-self to only one gallery-per-page. Instead take a look at [Authoring a jQuery Plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/).
- Websites are **responsive**, you cannot use `sliderWidth` as a constant - eventually try to recalculate the width on click...

```js
(function() {

  var sliderWidth = $('.carousel-cells').width();

  var Carousel = {
    init: function() {
      Carousel.bindEvents();
      
      // You're missign the initial insertion
      // and the negative margin (like in the codepen)
      // This helps to go prev without nuisances. 
      $('.carousel-cells').css({marginLeft: -sliderWidth});
      $('article:last-child').prependTo('.carousel-cells');
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
      $(".carousel-next").on("click", Carousel.next);
      $(".carousel-prev").on("click", Carousel.previous);
      $(document).on("keydown", function(e) { // you need only one listener
        var key = e.which; // Use Event.which instead of keyCode
        if (key===37) Carousel.previous();
        if (key===39) Carousel.next();
      });
    },
    next: function() {
      $('.carousel-cells').animate({
        left: -sliderWidth
      }, 500, function() {
        $('article:first-child').appendTo('.carousel-cells');
        // you don't want to reset left of "article" but ".carousel-cells"
        $('.carousel-cells').css('left', 0);
      });
    },
    previous: function() {
      $('.carousel-cells').animate({
        left: +sliderWidth
      }, 500, function() {
        $('article:last-child').prependTo('.carousel-cells');
        // you don't want to reset left of "article" but ".carousel-cells"
        $('.carousel-cells').css('left', 0);
      });
    }
    // TODO: update, props
  }
  
  
  $( Carousel.init );
  
})(window);
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/ *{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;} html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}

.page-content .main-carousel {
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #c0ffee;
}
.page-content .main-carousel .carousel-cells {
  position:relative; /* neeed since you're animating positions */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
}
.page-content .main-carousel .carousel-cells article {
  flex: 1 0 100%; /* stretch to parent's 100% */
  width: 100%;
  /* inner elements related: */
  display: flex;  
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* (all important was above. Now go with Buttons and stuff...) */
.page-content .main-carousel .carousel-next,
.page-content .main-carousel .carousel-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
.page-content .main-carousel .carousel-next {
  right: 0;
}
.page-content .main-carousel .carousel-prev {
  left: 0;
}
.slide-text h1 {
  font-size: 8vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-content">
  <section class="main-carousel">
    <div class="carousel-cells">
      <article>
        <div class="slide-text">
          <h1>Slide One</h1>
          <p>A slide about sliding slides.</p>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article>
        <div class="slide-text">
          <h1>Slide Two</h1>
          <p>A slide-sliding slider sliding slides.</p>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article>
        <div class="slide-text">
          <h1>Slide Three</h1>
          <p>A slide-sliding slider sliding slides.</p>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
    <!-- Instead of using z-index place where due -->
    <div class="carousel-next">&gt;</div>
    <div class="carousel-prev">&lt;</div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How to write below code without animate function,

```
    next: function() {
      $('.carousel-cells').animate({
        left: -sliderWidth
      }, 500, function() {
        $('article:first-child').appendTo('.carousel-cells');
        $('.carousel-cells').css('left', 0);
      });
    },
    previous: function() {
      $('.carousel-cells').animate({
        left: +sliderWidth
      }, 500, function() {
        $('article:last-child').prependTo('.carousel-cells');
        $('.carousel-cells').css('left', 0);
      });
    }
```